# Proof from Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have tried upto where I could. please anyone help me to complete my proof..

[image]

Help much appreciated

Comment: It should only be a matter of plug in and calculate (as you have rightfully done), if I am not missing some preferable trick. I am sure there will be a matter of trig identities.

Comment: But I couldn't get the desired result...

Comment: Do you know how to multiply the two matrices at the bottom of the page?

Comment: You could try using the identity $ \tan {\dfrac {\alpha }{2}}={\dfrac {1-\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}}$

Comment: Greg Martin, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I therefore ends your calculations:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \frac{\sin \frac \alpha 2}{\cos \frac \alpha 2} \\
-\frac{\sin \frac \alpha 2}{\cos \frac \alpha 2} & 1
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \alpha  & -\sin \alpha  \\
\sin \alpha  & \cos \alpha
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \alpha +\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha }\sin \alpha  &
-\sin \alpha +\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha }\cos \alpha
\\
-\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha }\cos \alpha +\sin \alpha
& \cos \alpha +\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha }\sin \alpha
\end{array}
\right) $ ;

so developing the expressions, in the last matrix,  using trigonometric forms,

$\sin \alpha =2\sin \frac \alpha 2\cos \frac \alpha 2$

$\cos \alpha =2\cos ^2\frac \alpha 2-1$

$\cos ^2\frac \alpha 2+\sin ^2\frac \alpha 2=1$,

the result is obtained as
 $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha } \\
\frac{\sin \frac 12\alpha }{\cos \frac 12\alpha } & 1
\end{array}
\right) $